# "Fingerprint cannot be generated" when adding new SSH key to gitlab account

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to add a new ssh key to my GitLab account but I keep getting following errors:

```
Fingerprint cannot be generated
Key type is forbidden. Must be RSA, ECDSA, or ED25519
```

What I've done is gone to Cmder and entered the commands

```
ssh-keygen
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then I've copied the key into my school GitLab account trough a web browser and got the errors mentioned above.

Why is this happening, and how can I successfully upload my key?

Answer (score 12):

You need to do the following instead of just `ssh-keygen`:

```
 ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "email@example.com"
```

This creates a ED25519 key that can be used with Gitlab. Make sure to change the email to your email (associated with the gitlab account). Then take the newly generated .pub key and copy it into the same place you were before.

Source:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/

Comment: I tried eactly what you said but am still getting the exact same errors.

Comment: @DávidČano Will you try:
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "email@example.com" 
This is the suggested key type; ED25519.

Comment: That finally worked, thank you so much! You've just saved my sanity.

Comment: @DávidČano I edited my answer to reflect the proper steps. Would you mind submitting it as the answer if you feel it answers your question?

Comment: RSA keys should be fine. That's one of the key types listed in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance that you're copying and pasting newline characters from your key wrapping in the terminal that should not be there.

When you paste your key it should all be one one line. It probably starts with `ssh-rsa` (if you generate an RSA key; other key types will start similarly) and end with something like `you@machine`. There should be a space after `ssh-rsa` and one before `you@machine`, but no newlines should exist.

Either manually remove newlines when you paste or open the file in a proper text editor where you can copy it without newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error then used SSH key generated by terraform and used output of:

```
public_key_pem
```

Fixed by using output of

```
public_key_openssh
```

Answer (score 0):

After generating the SSH key using -

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "<comment>"`

Then two files will be generated `id_ed25519`  and  `id_ed25519.pub`

Open `id_ed25519.pub` file in an code editor and copy paste the whole SSH key.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and in my specific case the problem was that I'd created a 4096 bit rsa key -- which was fine for ssh, but gitlab gave those misleading error messages.

After recreating it as a 2048 bit key, it just worked.